# Use ReactiveVar in {{each}} helper

Tags: meteor, meteor-helper

I have a ReactiveVar in my helper which returns a number of photos to be placed in a template

```
photoCount:->
    Template.instance().rvPhotoCount.get()
```

Now I need to reactively populate my html with a # of `img` returned by photoCount. I tried using `{{each photoCount}}<img>` but receive an error
`{{#each}} currently only accepts arrays, cursors or falsey values.`
How do I tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{{#each}}` operator is used for iterating over a list of things, such as, in your case, the list of your images.

Currently you are passing `{{#each}}` the *number* of images you have. And `each` does not know how to iterate over a single number!

If you want to display each of  the images, you should pass `each` the image list itself, in the form of an array or cursor:

```
{{#each images}}<img src={{src}} />{{/each}}
```

If you just want to display the *number* of images, just use `{{photoCount}}`!

```
<p>There are {{photoCount}} images.</p>
```

If you just want to print a number of the same "static" img, you'll have to pre-process the array in your helper:

```
  photoCount: function(){
    var countArr = [];
    var count = Template.instance().rvPhotoCount.get();
    for (var i=0; i<count; i++){
      countArr.push({});
    }
    return countArr;
  }
```

And use `{{#each}}` on it. Sadly, Meteor is very limited in terms of built-in templating functionalities.

Comment: Thanks! But I need to reactively change the number of images on the page. So how can I tell Meteor: `give me <img> 5 times` when I press button A?  And when I press button B `make them 3 <img>'s instead of 5`.

Comment: You confirmed my thoughts of the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to change helper output to an array for solution.
To populate the array I use coffeescript array slicing.

```
photoCount:->
    count=Template.instance().rvPhotoCount.get()
    array=[1..count]
```